# How to show row number in Smart Table?

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I would like to include the row number of the sorted and filtered dataset in Smart Table as a separate column.

As long as I do not use paging I can simply use the $index propery of angular's ng-repeat but this does not work where paging is enabled since $index starts on 0 for each page.

Anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do this:

1. Adding the following to the controller

```js
$scope.page_size = 100
$scope.current_page = 1
$scope.rembemberCurrentPage = function(p) {
  $scope.current_page = p
}
```

2. Adding the following to the template

```html
<div st-pagination 
     st-page-change="rembemberCurrentPage(newPage)" 
     st-items-by-page="page_size">
</div>
```

3.
Row number can then be accessed on the form

```html
td ng-bind="((current_page-1)*page_size)+$index+1"></td>
```

I figured it out through this post:
https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/438

Answer (score 2):

```
<td ng-bind="pageNum*pageSize + $index"></td>
```

Comment: Thank you. This does however not seem to work since the variables pageNum and pageSize does not seem to be visible within the st-table.

Comment: You can get them from the service where you do requests to load next page

Comment: you can also set/get them when you define your pagination and through the pipe function